# How to access objects that were initialized in a try statement

Tags: c++, exception, scope

I'm new to C++ and was wondering if you could do the following, or if you have a better way.

I have a custom exception class for my database handler: I use this in my main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char const ** argv){
    try {
        DatabaseHandler DGeneDB = DatabaseHandler("string/to/path");
    }catch(DatabaseHandlerExceptions &msg) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open Database" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << msg.what();
        return 1;
    }
    DGeneDB.foo() //Can't access this object since it was initialized in try statement
    return 0;
}
```

I have a billion things I want to do with the DGeneDB object and don't want to do it all within the try statement. I only want to catch the constructor exception that is thrown during initialization. What should I do to work with the object outside of try? I mean, if it throws the exception, it will return 1 and will stop main() before it gets to the other object.

Comment: Do all the work inside the try block. But what does this have to do with having a custom exception class?

Comment: Why do you need to access them outside of the `try` block?

Comment: I was thinking that if any other method throws a different exception it might make it more difficult. I guess I could always use a lot of nested trys. But I guess the answer is "you can't do this"

Comment: @jwillis0720 Either nested, or several catch blocks for other exceptions at the end. You can do it using pointers, but I wouldn't recommend to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Does this really need downvotes though? I thought it was a pretty legit question for a c++ beginner.

Comment: There's quite a lot of irrelevant code in your question. Maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Problem is though. You really don't know it's irrelevant until you know the answer. But I removed the irrelevant parts anyway.

Comment: In this case it's difficult to say, but normally, lots of small try-catch clauses are a bad idea. The thing that makes this difficult is that here it is one that spans the entire main() function, which is pretty normal again. Keep this single one in main() with all the code inside, only that you catch a generic std::exception there. Then, if you really need to handle specific errors in smaller parts, add exception handlers there.

Comment: @jwillis0720 Part of problem solving is to reduce and isolate problems. If you really think there is an issue with your custom exception and your DB class, remove that and use something simpler.

Comment: Two more comments: Why do you call `DGeneDB.foo()` without catching and logging errors from there? Secondly, you can use multiple catch statements following a single try statement, in this case I would consider one for `DatabaseHandlerExceptions` (really exception*S*?) and one for the baseclass `std::exception`.

Comment: Obviously the code that uses the object should be inside the `try` block that initializes it. There is no other way to write it. Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your `Databasehandler` have an `open` method, or something similar? If not, create one and modify that constructor so that it doesn't open the database connection anymore (so it won't throw). Your code would look like this:

```
DatabaseHandler DGenDB;
try {
    DGenDB.open(dbpaths.Dgene_db);
}
catch (DatabaseHandlerExceptions &msg) {
    return 1;
}
```

**Note:** In your original code you have a line like this:

```
DatabaseHandler DGeneDB = DatabaseHandler(dbpaths.Dgene_db);
```

That is an unusual way to initialize variables in C++. You could have just written:

```
DatabaseHandler DGeneDB(dbpaths.Dgene_db);
```

Comment: This goes against the RAII principle (not that it's compulsory to follow that of course)

Comment: @MattMcNabb It doesn't, the same way `std::ifstream` or `std::ofstream` don't. Nothing prevents you from closing the connection in the destructor, even if you have an `open` method.

Comment: It does go against the RAII principle, just as `fstream`s do with their `open()` functions. However, RAII is cumbersome unless you have move semantics, so having an `open()` function in `fstream`s is well justified, IMHO. For new code, this shouldn't be repeated though, so maybe the simplest solution to the immediate request is to just declare the object outside and move an initialized object into it inside the try block.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt When you say that it doesn't follow RAII, is it because the constructor is not opening the connection? RAII (despite its confusing name) is about having a resource be automatically managed by an object.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If having a constructor that does not allocate/ open a resource is not RAII, then not even `std::unique_ptr` is RAII. In fact, most of the stuff in the standard library is not RAII.

Comment: I think there is no clear definition of RAII that allows saying either is right. To me, the idea of RAII is to tie the management of a resource to the lifetime/scope of an object. In this strict sense, it is not always applicable, hence `open()` and `close()` or move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer:

```
DatabaseHandler *DGeneDB;
try {
    DGeneDB = new DatabaseHandler("string/to/path");
}catch(DatabaseHandlerExceptions &msg) {
    // your error stuff here
}
DGeneDB->foo();
```

But don't forget to delete it after use.

Comment: You should use a managed pointer like std::unique_ptr instead, this way you don't have the risk of leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to C++17 (and your type has a move constructor), you could use std::optional for that:

```cpp
std::optional<DatabaseHandler> database{};

try {
    database = DatabaseHandler{arguments};
}
catch (const YourExceptionTypeHere &exception) {
    // ...
    return 1;
}

database->foo();
```

This way you'll still be able to initialize the object in the try block as you wish, without having to modify your constructor or resorting to heap memory allocations (new/unique_ptr).

If the pointer like syntax/nature of std::optional bothers you,
you could also move the object out of the std::optional after you initialize it:

```cpp
DatabaseHandler real_database{std::move(*database)};

real_database.foo();
```